# Why charge is an extensive property

Tags: thermodynamics

While reading examples of extensive properties, I cam across electric charge. Can someone please explain to me why electric charge is considered to be an extensive property?

We know that extensive properties are those that depend on mass, but I cannot understand how electric charge depends on mass.

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/141284/2451

Comment: Hi P.A24. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: Where did you see that extensive properties depend on mass?

Comment: @Qmechanic, how can this be a duplicate of a closed question. It seems this says: "Look we have an answer there already, but we dont like it so we closed it" :)

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia [Intensive and extensive properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensive_and_extensive_properties)

> By contrast, an extensive property is one that is additive for
>   independent, noninteracting subsystems.[1] The property is
>   proportional to the amount of material in the system. For example,
>   both the mass and the volume of a diamond are directly proportional to
>   the amount that is left after cutting it from the raw mineral. Mass
>   and volume are extensive properties, but hardness is intensive.

Since the total charge of 2 charged particles is the sum of the each of the charges, charge is an extensive property (**depends on system size/dimensions**)

UPDATE:

Plus it should be mentioned that from an extensive property one can construct an intensive property (e.g from **mass** one can contruct **density**) (under the conditions this holds)

And from an intensive property one can construct an extensive property (e.g from **density** construct **mass**)  (under the conditions this holds).